# URL link for Google Maps in attribute table splitted after "," upload to WebGIS (QGIS Cloud)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, url, web-gis, qgis-cloud

In my attribute table, I'm constructing a link that allows to call google maps and navigate to a position by car. I'm following the [developer guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) and my URLs look as follows: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Long,Lat&travelmode=driving`.
These links work fine from within QGIS and also if I just copy paste them in the browser-windwo e.g. on a tablet - it opens the Browser or google maps and starts the navigation with the coordinates as the destination.

This is, how I construct the URL:

[image]

And this is the URL:

[image]

However, after the upload to QGIS Cloud, this link is broken after the "," between Lat/Long which is the standard format for the URL. Obviously this breaks the link and the navigation cannot be started.

How can I prevent QGIS Cloud from separating the URL after the "," ?

[image]

There are some questions that appear to be slightly realted but are ~7ish years old. Such as this one: [x and y coordinates will only display [x],[y] when field calculator is used to make a url](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151489/x-and-y-coordinates-will-only-display-x-y-when-field-calculator-is-used-to-m).
However the main issue there is, to construct the link. My links seem to work well, but QGIS Cloud is not able to display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acutally quite simple. I just figured it out, but want to leave it here in case anyone else is running into this issue:

I was **lacking the HTML-Encoding**.

Instead of:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Long,Lat&travelmode=driving`

I should have written:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Long%2CLat&travelmode=driving`.

Hence **replacing** the `,` with `%2C`.