# Creating a hyperlink in QGIS doesn't work

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, html, hyperlink

I have a text in an attribute table that contains a file path. I want a hyperlink to be displayed in the information about the object - in blue, underlined - as I saw in this tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

I changed the widget type in the attribute form to Text Edit-> Multiline-> HTML but after saving the changes still the object is identified as normal text.
Have I done something wrong?

BTW: I have active path open action from this attribute and it works.

[image: 1st screenshot]

[image: 2nd screenshot]

Comment: Yes, sure! https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

Comment: could this be realted to the encoding - e.g. see this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458580/url-link-for-google-maps-in-attribute-table-splitted-after-in-qgis-cloud

Comment: rename the dashes and dots in your local drive or move your local url to c:/web replaces spaces ect with underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. A normal website link does indeed highlight blue, so it works. My goal is to create a map application (using the QGIS2Web plugin) that has a link in one of its attributes.

Comment: See my answer, that should work in QGIS. However, exporting to QGIS2Web might not work as style/formatting etc. is not 100% compatible. You might need to re-program at least parts of your map.

Comment: Just tested: exporting with QGIS2Web to OpenLayers, clicking on the points opens a form with the attributes. Hyperlink works for the URL (feature 3 in my example), not for the filepath (feature 2). Asking about how you can create an URL that works after exporting with QGIS2Web is another question and you should post a new question for that 8you might link to this one here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure the filepath is recognized as such and not as a html link, use a `file:///` prefix before the actual filepath - like in this example:

```
file:///C:/Users/DU/Desktop/my_image.jpg
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to open the link

*Screenshot: feature 1 with no link, features 2 and 3 will open the file/website with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>*
[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and it kind of worked with your solution - however not for relative paths. The relative paths are shown as a link to a file, but nothing opens.

Comment: You should post a separate question for that. You can link to this one here.